# I have a progressbar, but I want it to stop at 100% and reload the site to redirect users to the next step

Tags: redirect, progress-bar

okay as I said in the title I already got a working fake progressbar.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #progress-bar-wrapper
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 2px;
        }

        #progress-bar
        {
                background-color: #a1cee8;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { animateProgressBar() });

        function animateProgressBar()
        {
                $("#progress-bar")
                .css("width", "0%")
                .animate(
                {
                        width: "100%"
                },
                1550, //Speed of loading bar
                animateProgressBar);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progress-bar-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This progressbar is being put in a pre-loader-site and what I want it to do is that **once it reaches 100%, it must stop and then reload/redirect** the user to the next site..

I have this idea in mind, but I guess it has to be changed a bit in order to be applied:
Progressbar loads, reaches 100% (this happens succesfully with the code provided above), however, it must stop at 100%. AND when it does, it must load an immediate redirection to the next site.

Hope everything is clear, thank you very much!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured this out with the support of a friend:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=0;
//var y=5;
window.onload=progress();

function progress(){
    var timer;

    if(x<100){
        x+=1;
        document.getElementById('progressbar').style.width=x+'%';            
        timer=setTimeout('progress()',-40);
    }else{
        clearTimeout(timer);
        location.href='http://siteexample.com/index.html';
    }
}
</script>
```

The variable x has a default value of 0. *windows.onload* launches the progress, the bar fills itself according to the if-statement that it's *<100* with x+=1 (this allowed me to imitate the smooth JQuery-animateProgressBar effect). The next two lines are just about the bar itself *(getElementById looks for the CSS ID called 'progressbar' and setTimeout is just the time in ms between one call and the other)*

Then, when it's bigger than 100 *(else, x<100)* the timer is cleared and a new location is loaded *location.href='http://siteexample.com/index.html*.

Hope it's useful to someone else, too.
Chris
(the commented var y=5 is still for testing; i'm trying to create a slowing-down effect on the progressbar.)